# a simple typographical erro

Tags: c++, ubuntu-15.10

gcc -wall -w -werror hello.cpp -o hello

show me : gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-wall’
    ,and  ==> gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-werror’

Comment: `-Wall -Werror`

Comment: try -Wall with capital W

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try -**W**all with captial W. The command line options are case senstive.

> -Wall This enables all the warnings about constructions that some users consider questionable, and that are easy to avoid (or modify to
>   prevent the warning), even in conjunction with macros. This also
>   enables some language-specific warnings described in C++ Dialect
>   Options and Objective-C and Objective-C++ Dialect Options.

And for the werror, use -**W**error with captial W

> -Werror=
>   Make the specified warning into an error. The specifier for a warning is appended; for example -Werror=switch turns the warnings controlled by -Wswitch into errors. This switch takes a negative form, to be used to negate -Werror for specific warnings; for example -Wno-error=switch makes -Wswitch warnings not be errors, even when -Werror is in effect.
>   The warning message for each controllable warning includes the option that controls the warning. That option can then be used with -Werror= and -Wno-error= as described above. (Printing of the option in the warning message can be disabled using the -fno-diagnostics-show-option flag.)
>
> Note that specifying -Werror=foo automatically implies -Wfoo. However, -Wno-error=foo does not imply anything.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

Comment: Such a low quality post doesn't deserve an answer.

Comment: In your opnion? i'm just trying to help someone out who's obviously new, and this is an easy oversight to make when new.

Comment: Also, when searching in google, there are no newbie friendly answers in the first results, so this might actually be a useful question for stackoverflow.